# Wix throws away components that are marked as NeverOverWrite="yes"

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I've created an installer that upgrades our software, but for some reason the XML configuration files (those of our software) are removed when upgrading.

This appears to happen if all features of the software are upgraded.
Our software is an archive type thing. If I install just that feature and upgrade it everything is fine.

However, if I install all services accompanying the archive and upgrade those then all configuration files (and each is in a different folder!) are gone.

As an example:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="AutoArchiveTool" Directory="AutoArchiverFolder">
     <Component Id="C_AutoArchivingTool_Gateway_exe_config" NeverOverwrite="yes" Guid="{A62D5200-FDE0-4DA1-A04A-7FBDACEA83B2}">
       <File Id="F_AutoArchivingTool_Gateway_exe_config" Source="$(var.Gateway.TargetDir)Gateway.exe.config" KeyPath="yes"/>
     </Component>
... more script
</ComponentGroup>
```

If you log the installer you can even see that it's recognized as "never overwrite":

```
Disallowing installation of component: {A62D5200-FDE0-4DA1-A04A-7FBDACEA83B2} since the keyfile exists and the component is marked to never overwrite existing installations
```

Yet it's gone after the upgrade. What am I missing?
I've see the "Permanent" property, but that's not what I want. I want the installer to leave the config files alone during an upgrade. Not leave them (config files) after removal.

Comment: I think if you just do nothing it will not overwrite if the user has modified it after it was installed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

NeverOverwrite does not mean "don't uninstall" so:

a) if the component ID changes between the original install and the new one the sharing won't work as you intend and the ref count will decrement and the file will be removed, this being when the upgrade is scheduled "late", such as afterInstallExecute.

b) If the upgrade is scheduled early (such as afterInstallInitialize) all the old product is uninstalled first, then the new product is installed. You haven't said where your upgrade is sequenced, but sometimes Windows Installer screws up in an "early" upgrade: it decides that the file won't be overwritten, but fails to re-evaluate this when the install turns out to be an upgrade. In this case your upgrade will complete and the file will be missing. If you have this issue then a repair of the product will restore the file from the *new* version of the product (because that is the current owner of the component). This won't help.

So make sure that the component ID didn't change and your upgrade is scheduled late, such as afterInstallExecute. In addition, do the upgrade with verbose logging to verify what's going on.

Having said all that, NeverOverwrite is often used to solve a problem that doesn't exist. The file overwrite rules (that are invoked by a "late" upgrade) say that modified files won't be overwritten:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

So if the first setup installs the file, then it gets updated by the app, then your upgrade runs it will not replace the modified file anyway, and there is no need to set NeverOverwrite.

Comment: I've changed the sequence to "afterInstallExecute" and now it works! So thank you for that!

Comment: I wanted to see if I could loose the "NeverOverwrite". The file is xml without version so the installer should leave them alone a per the msdn article. But when I did so, I got this in the logging: `Action 13:11:03: ExecXmlFile. 
ExecXmlFile:  Error 0x8007006e: failed to load XML file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Services\SomeSource\SomeSource.exe.config
Error 25531. Failed to open XML file C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Services\SomeSource\SomeSource.exe.config, system error: -2147024786`. That is probably the `util:XmlFile` failing. But why? Files are on the system already.